# LLVM references a header which does not exist

Tags: c++, llvm

I've downloaded LLVM and Clang from SVN, built them, and written a tiny sample program. However, the LLVM headers (`llvm/support/type_traits.h`) appear to include another LLVM header, `llvm/support/DataTypes.h`, which does not exist. I checked the documentation on the LLVM website and they don't seem to think it should exist either.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I appear to have it: `find /opt/clang -name DataTypes.h` produced `/opt/clang/3.3/include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h`. I did this last week on ubuntu (a few glitches but eventually succeeded). Interestingly, it is not in the sources I got from svn but is in the build directory so something must create it.

Comment: Comment from inside my version of the file: `Generated from DataTypes.h.in by configure`

Comment: Can confirm: `/* include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h.  Generated from DataTypes.h.in by configure.  */`.

Comment: I have a DataTypes.h.in, it seems, but no DataTypes.h.

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html, step 6 will create it. If you have not touched your clang repository for some time, you'd better checkit out again.

Comment: I'm using VS, and did build as instructed in that guide. I pulled from SVN less than a week ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some file are auto-generated into the build directory. When compiling your programs to use LLVM as a library, always use the `llvm-config` tool to provide you with the right header directories and library directories for linking. I have this in my `Makefile`:

```
LLVM_CONFIG_COMMAND = `$(LLVM_BIN_PATH)/llvm-config --cxxflags --libs` \
                      `$(LLVM_BIN_PATH)/llvm-config --ldflags`
```

And I use it on the compiler command-line.

```
LLVM_BIN_PATH = $(LLVM_BUILD_PATH)/Debug+Asserts/bin
```

Where `LLVM_BUILD_PATH` is the path where you ran `configure`, and the rest of it depends on which version you have built (I usually use the Debug+Asserts one for hacking inside LLVM).

Comment: It is very unhelpful that they don't mention that half the headers are built and not placed into the include directory correctly.

Comment: @DeadMG: you appear to be an experienced programmer, so it must be not your first open-source project encounter. I wonder why you're surprised at the documentation :-)